# Share Zipped Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, zip, sharing

I'd like to share my unity project with some friends. Unfortunately, the project folder is large and I'm not sure about what files are generated automatically and can be safety deleted.

What files/folders can I delete and after that, if I zip the project folder and share it with my friends, they can use it?

Comment: Why not using Version Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `Assets` folder and `ProjectSettings` folder are needed.

Just compress them and send to your friend. They should use the same version of Unity3D as yours for compatibility.

Comment: Probably best to also send the project settings folder, that has all the layers and tags etc...